# ajax force page refresh after success?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call and after it success, it force a refresh or re-submit on the current page.  I have the e.preventDefault to stop this so this is confusing.  I do not want to re-submit or refresh on the page when i click submit on the form, I want to call ajax and put its content on the page. This is asp mvc4. I know it does call the method right and got a result from it.  The alert I putted in the success call did pop up and have the correct content, but after I click ok, it look like the page re-submit or refresh.

```
<form id="multiple3And5Form" action="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Multiples of 3 and 5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="number" name="multiple3And5" id="multiple3And5" min="0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p id="multiple3And5_answer">

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" name="submit_multiple3And5" id="submit_multiple3And5" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#multiple3And5Form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        var inputData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("multiple3And5Method")',
            data: inputData,
            success: function (result) { $('#multiple3And5_answer').html("Answer: "+result); alert(result); },
            error: function (error) { alert(error.status); $('#multiple3And5_answer').html(error); }
        });//end ajax
    }//end function(e) near .submit
    );//end submit

</script>

public JsonResult multiple3And5Method(int multiple3And5)
        {
            int answer = 0;
            for(int i = 1;i<multiple3And5;i++)
            {
                if(i%3==0 | i%5==0)
                {
                    answer += i;
                }
            }

            return Json(answer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Why not just use `<button type="button" ...>` and handle its `.click()` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On Ajax success submit form

```
<form id="multiple3And5Form" action="">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Multiples of 3 and 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="number" name="multiple3And5" id="multiple3And5" min="0">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p id="multiple3And5_answer">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="display: none">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_multiple3And5"   
    id="submit_multiple3And5" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div class="col-md-2">
<input type="button" name="btnNmae" id="btnId" value="Submit">
</div>
```

> JS

```
$('#btnId').click( function(e) {
 var numVal = $('#multiple3And5').val();
 $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
       url: '@Url.Action("multiple3And5Method")',
     data: { inputData: numVal },
     success: function (result) {
         $('#multiple3And5_answer').html("Answer: " + result); alert(result);
         $('#multiple3And5Form').submit();
     },
        error: function (error) { alert(error.status); $('#multiple3And5_answer').html(error); }
     });//end ajax
});
```